# Invalid hook call on share function

Tags: react-hooks

I'm new to react and I'm creating share common function for updating the project status. The purpose of this is to reuse this function on other module. However I'm facing run time error on invalid hook call ( Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component). How should I change the function to fix the invalid hook call ?

```
export async function updateStatus(sectionId:number, statusId: number ) {
  useEffect(() => {
    const {updateProSecStatus} = useUpProSecStatus(); // GQL Mutation 
    const {setAlertMsg} = useContext(AlertMsgContext);

    const fetchData = async () => {
      let res = await updateProSecStatus({
        projectSectionid: sectionId,
        statusId: statusId,
      });

      if (res.errors) {
        setAlertMsg({
          message: 'Error: Failed to update status',
          variant: 'error',
        });
      }

    };

     fetchData;

  });
}
```

Comment: please show us where you call the function itself.

Answer (score 0):

i am not much sure but you can try this once....

write this both line at the Top level where your Component starts

```
const {updateProSecStatus} = useUpProSecStatus(); // GQL Mutation 
    const {setAlertMsg} = useContext(AlertMsgContext);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs when one of these [rules](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) for hooks is violated.

So check each of them. For example make sure that you are calling your hook in function components or other hooks only (not in class components or regular js functions)

> Only Call Hooks from React Functions Don’t call Hooks from regular
> JavaScript functions. Instead, you can:
>
> ✅ Call Hooks from React function components.
>
> ✅ Call Hooks from custom hooks

Also interesting from this [page](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html) of react docs:

> A custom Hook is a **JavaScript function whose name starts with ”use”**
> and that may call other Hooks. For example, useFriendStatus below is
> our first custom Hook

So make sure to rename your function to something like:
`useUpdateStatus`.